# Can I create a different page layout just for the creation of an object?

Tags: page-layout, create-records

We have way too many fields on the oppty object. I am trying to create a new page layout, that will be used only upon the creation of a new oppty. That will holda roughly 15-20 fields only that are needed for the creation.

We use LEX, when a user clicks the 'New' button, I want that the page will show the needed fields. upon save, the user will see the regualr pages.

I don't want to use different stages or record types for this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to try with record types, you can try below way -

You can override button with custom VF page/lightning component or you can design your visual flow, to create record(with set of fields).

With LDS in Lightning and with Visual flow, you don't need to have Apex class. However, with lightning styling part(and UX as well) can be controlled.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not wish to override new button, create a custom [quick action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5) in lightning as "Quick Create Opportunity" that launches a custom lightning web or a aura component.

In the component, you can use a the [record edit form base component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) to show the appropriate fields with minimal code and on save you can navigate to newly created record. This all would just need a LWC component without any apex or flows.